# Generic AsynTask Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have made a lot of project and for every web-serves i make a a AsyncTask class. If i want to get data from 20 web-serves then i have to make 20 A AsyncTask classes . so this is not the use-ability code.Any one help me to make a Generic AsyncTask class so in whole project i have just 1 AsyncTask class and i use that class.

```
    public class HTTPAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private CallBack mCb;
    HashMap<String, String> mData = null;
    List<NameValuePair> mParams= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String mTypeOfRequest;
    String mStrToBeAppended = "";
    boolean isPostDataInJSONFormat = false;
    JSONObject mJSONPostData = null;

    public HTTPAsyncTask(CallBack c, HashMap<String, String> data, JSONObject jsonObj, String request) {
        mCb = c;
        mTypeOfRequest = request;
        mJSONPostData = jsonObj;
        if((data != null) && (jsonObj == null)){
            mData = data;
            if(mTypeOfRequest.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
                Iterator<String> it = mData.keySet().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    String key = it.next();
                    mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, mData.get(key)));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i<mParams.size()-1; i++){
                    mStrToBeAppended+= "?" + mParams.get(i).getName() + "=" + mParams.get(i).getValue() + "&"; 
                }
                //add the last parameter without the "&"
                mStrToBeAppended+= "?" + mParams.get(mParams.size()-1).getName() + "=" + mParams.get(mParams.size()-1).getValue();

            }

            if(mTypeOfRequest.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
                    Iterator<String> it = mData.keySet().iterator();
                    while(it.hasNext()){
                        String key = it.next();
                        mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, mData.get(key)));
                    }
            }

        }
        if ((mData == null) && (jsonObj != null)){
            isPostDataInJSONFormat = true;
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... baseUrls) {

        publishProgress(null);
        if(mTypeOfRequest.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
            String finalURL = baseUrls[0]+ mStrToBeAppended;
             return HttpUtility.GET(finalURL);
        }

        if (mTypeOfRequest.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
            if(isPostDataInJSONFormat == false){
                return HttpUtility.POST(baseUrls[0],mParams );
            }
            else {
                return HttpUtility.POST(baseUrls[0], mJSONPostData);
            }

        }

        return null;

    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       mCb.onResult(result);


   }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...voids ) {
        mCb.onProgress();
   }
```

Comment: Well you can make one AsynTask for all 20 web communications but unfortunately they will not work in parallel as you wanted. In order to do parallel work you might use Runnable and not AsynkTask. AsynTask is usually used when you want to update the GUI

Comment: "unfortunately they will not work in parallel as you wanted" -- yes, they will, if you use `executeOnExecutor()`.

Comment: Sir i just want one ASYNCTASK that will use in whole project . i know u are telling about thread but plz first understand my Q